# I need to add a dynamic date variable in a BigQuery query via Klipfolio

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, klipfolio

I've got user data in BigQuery, from a Firebase app. I using Klipfolio to extract date. I want to extract engaged user data from a time range selected by the user. I, therefore, need to add dynamic date variables in my SQL query. Klipfolio supports using dynamic date variables in a query. It's the syntax for introducing a start and end date variable I'm not sure about.

I can already extract the data by date - but such a table does not work for engaged users as the same users will be counted multiple times.

**standardSQL**

```
SELECT
event_date,
count (distinct user_pseudo_id) AS engagedUsers

FROM

 `dataTable`

WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'


  GROUP BY
  event_date

ORDER BY
event_date
```

I'm looking for the number of active users between a start and end date variable.

Comment: Why not add user_pseudo_id to the group by part of the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have want to filter user data based on a 'event_date' field in your table and by start and end dates coming from date pickers in Klipfolio and you have used variable names "start_date" and "end_date", your SQL query can look like this:

```
SELECT
event_date,
count (distinct user_pseudo_id) AS engagedUsers

FROM

 `dataTable`

WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement' and
  event_date >='{props.start_date}' and 
  event_date <= '{props.end_date}'


  GROUP BY
  event_date

ORDER BY
event_date
```

"props" calls the variable value in Klipfolio defined after the dot and swaps that in before sending the query to the specified service.

Ensure your output format of your date pickers are in yyyy-MM-dd to match the valid format for your SQL query.